# Angular 5 error with "@angular/core" after installing bootstrap 4

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, angular5

I am building my first application using angular 5 and .net core2 in visual studio 2017; I am using .Net core2 to create APIs and handle data through models... and those APIs are called from client side using angular 5; In order to make my web app responsive I decided to use Bootstrap 4; Before i installed it, dependencies where working fine, everything was great as you can see here :

[image]

But when after I installed bootstrap successfully using this command: `npm install bootstrap --save` suddenly an error appeared in the dependencies and I can't be able anymore to build my solution...

Why this error appeared and how can I solve it? Please note that I have created a pure angular5 using visual studio 2017 and I did the same --> installation worked successfully and I was able to use bootstrap 4;

[image]

Error:

[image]

**Update:**

In order to solve my error I have tried this:

```
npm install

npm i @angular/core
```

But below error was thrown:

> Could not install from ""@angular\core"^5.2.0"," as it does not
>   contain a package.json file

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "\"@angular/core\"^5.2.0\",",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try installing @angular/core again ?

Comment: @CornelC please check my updated question

Comment: In package.json the angular/core dependency is wrong `"@angular/core": "\"@angular/core\"^5.2.0\",",` . I should be `"@angular/core": "^5.2.0"`

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `package.json` is wrong.

Replace 
`"@angular/core": "\"@angular/core\"^5.2.0\",",`

with 
`"@angular/core": "^5.2.0"`